# Para que servem os Events no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, framework

Nunca utilizei Event no Laravel e gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade e se tem alguma vantagem.

Comment: Criei meu cadastro só pra agradecer pela resposta que eu nem procurava, por acaso acabei aqui, meus parabéns pela explicação.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É uma funcionalidade do Laravel que provê meio de você poder "escutar" os eventos que ocorrem internamente dentro da sua aplicação.

A aplicação escrita em Laravel (assim como outras aplicações) possuem cada etapa bem definidas:

- Processamento da requisição
- Renderização das respostas
- Conexão com o banco de dados
- Processamento da sessão
- Usuário logando ou deslogando
- Tentativa de login

Enfim, são vários eventos que ocorrem dentro de uma aplicação escrita em Laravel até chegar a resposta ao usuário final.

Através desses Events, é possível disparar um evento para identificar algo que está sendo feito em uma determinada etapa.

Assim, ao você definir um "ouvinte" (ou "observador) para esse evento, ele será executado assim que esse evento for disparado.

Por exemplo, é possível verificar o que está acontecendo quando uma view está em processo de inicio ou fim de renderização.

## Exemplo

Vou dar um exemplo simples para você entender: O processo de captura da rota. Quando a expressão de uma url casa com a expressão que você definiu em uma rota, um evento é disparado. Falando especificamente do Laravel 5, trata-se da classe chamada `Illuminate\Routing\Events\RouteMatched`.

Para você "escutar" o evento disparado quando uma rota é capturada, você pode usar a classe `Event` para fazer isso.

Podemos definir esse "ouvinte" dentro da classe `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    \Event::listen(\Illuminate\Routing\Events\RouteMatched::class, function ($request) {

        dd('Evento da rota está sendo escutado');

    });
}
```

**Observação**: A expressão `\Illuminate\Routing\Events\RouteMatched::class` retorna uma `string`. Ou seja, o nome do evento é o nome da classe e seu respectivo namespace.

No exemplo acima, quando você acessar qualquer rota válida, o Laravel executará o ouvinte que você registrou para `'\Illuminate\Routing\Events\RouteMatched'`, que no caso é o evento referente à captura de rotas.

**Mas quem fez o evento ser disparado?**

Internamente, quando uma rota é encontrada, o `Laravel` utiliza um método chamado `Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher::fire`. Esse método é responsável por executar todos os "ouvintes" registrados para um determinado evento.

**Outros exemplos**

Ainda falando dos eventos internos, no Laravel temos, por exemplo, um evento disparado na criação de uma conexão com o banco, que pode ter um *ouvinte/observador*, que tomará uma decisão que você definir ao ser disparado.

**Criando meu próprio evento**

É possível você criar seu próprio evento que será disparado assim que uma ação for executada.

Você poderia querer disparar um evento toda vez que uma determinado toda vez que um usuário acessasse a rota `/admin` após as 18 horas da tarde (lembrando que isso é apenas um simples exemplo).

Então, poderíamos ter algo como:

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);
     // Esse é o responsável por "ouvir/observar" um evento
    \Event::listen('admin.fora_de_expediente', function () {
         // Meu ouvinte faz um registro no banco
        DB::table('usuarios_logados_apos_18_horas')->insert([
             'usuario_id' => auth()->user()->id,
             'data_do_acesso' => new \DateTime
        ]);

    });
}
```

Em `routes.php`, poderíamos definir:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

    if (date('H') >= 18) {
        // Esse é o responsável por disparar o "evento"
        Event::fire('admin.fora_de_expediente');
    }

    // Todas as definições de rotas do Administrador
});
```

No exemplo acima, toda vez que um usuário entrasse em uma rota que tivesse o prefixo `admin`, após as 18 horas, teríamos um dado inserido no banco.

Note que o interessante dessa definição, é que você pode definir um ouvinte uma vez, porém disparar o evento em vários lugares, tornando seu código reutilizável e sem repetições inúteis.

**Nota**: A classe `Event` citada em trechos da resposta trata-se de um alias para a classe `Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher`.

Leituras recomendadas:

- [Laravel.com - Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#firing-events)
- [Discussion - List of Events avaliable in Laravel 5](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-can-i-get-a-complete-list-of-laravel-5-events?page=1)

Comment: Que explicação mais top. Meus parabéns!